# Ember.js - cannot createRecord app.mode.createRecord or this.store.createRecord

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I created a model with an Ember app, and I'm trying to add a record to the model but I keep getting an error saying undefind is not a function.

```
window.Aplus = Ember.Application.create();

Aplus.Store = DS.Store.extend();

Aplus.ApplicationAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = this.serialize(record, { includeId: true });
    var url = type;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data
      }).then(function(data) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, data);
      }, function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
        Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
      });
    });
  }
});


Aplus.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('aplus', function() {
    this.route('agents');
  });
});

Aplus.Agent = DS.Model.extend({
  firstname: DS.attr('string'),
  lastname: DS.attr('string'),
  team: DS.attr('string'),
  position: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
});

Aplus.AplusRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var agentObjects = [];
    Ember.$.getJSON('/agents', function(agents) {
      console.log(agents);
      agents.forEach(function(agent) {
        console.log(agent);
        console.log(Aplus.Agent.createRecord({
          id: 1,
          firstname: 'Edmond',
          lastname: 'Dantes',
          team: 'all',
          position:'count',
          email: 'count@aplus.com'
        }).save());
        //agentObjects.pushObject(Aplus.Agent.createRecord(agent));
      })
    });
    return agentObjects;
  }
});
```

The code break on the line where I do `Aplus.Agent.createRecord({})`. I tried changing it `this.store.createRecord({})` and I get an error saying cannot read property createRecord of undefined. The route agents links with my node route and gets the proper data.

Why does this not work? Also why does `this.store.createRecord` return that store is undefined, I thought it would be defined by extending the DS.Store, and the createRecord would be defined in the extension of applicationAdapter, no?

I thought maybe my links might by old but I use these cdns and I think these are the updated versions

```
<script src="http://emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/getting-started/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.9.1/ember.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/1.0.0-beta.14.1/ember-data.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you lost the context of this inside the getJSON function, make a reference to this before you enter the function `var self = this;` then call `self.store.createRecord({})` instead

```
Aplus.AplusRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
  var agentObjects = [];
  var self = this;
  Ember.$.getJSON('/agents', function(agents) {
  console.log(agents);
  agents.forEach(function(agent) {
    console.log(agent);
    console.log(self.store.createRecord('agent', {
      id: 1,
      firstname: 'Edmond',
      lastname: 'Dantes',
      team: 'all',
      position:'count',
      email: 'count@aplus.com'
    }).save());
   })
  });
 return agentObjects;
 }
});
```

Comment: Yo you're the man, thank you, I got it to work, makes perfect sense too. One more question, how come Aplus.Agent.createRecord({}); doesnt work? Is there any different between the two?

Comment: you don't create records like that by referencing the model name, the correct way to create a record is store.createRecord('agent', { firstname: "Tom" }); where the first argument is the name of the model you want to create the record for http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_createRecord, can you mark my answer as correct?